# python script is not working for rails migrated Mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have written a Python script for parsing CSV and insert those values to a MySQL table.
The  parsing csv and inserting part as follows:

```
csv_data = csv.reader(open(file_path, "rb"))
data_list = []
count = 0
##Loop for inserting data to table in baches
for row in csv_data:
    data_row = []
    data_row.append(row[0])
    data_row.append(row[1])
    data_row.append(row[2])
    ##removing the fist row
    if count == 0:
        count += 1
        continue
    else:
        data_row.insert(0,keyword_type)
        sql_command = "insert into "+ table_name +"(keyword_type,old_keyword_id,old_keyword_name,master_keyword_name) values (\"" +data_row[0]+"\"," + data_row[1]+ ",\"" +data_row[2]+"\",\"" +data_row[3]+"\")"
        cursor.execute(sql_command)
```

It is perfectly working if we create a table manually by using create table command in MySQL.

But I need to integrate this in to a rails environment and insert data to a table that created using migration. But after running the program is executing successfully and not showing any error. But data is not entering in to table. This is the problem.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Where and how is the table created?

Comment: I'm assuming the syntax error in the `sql_command` string is a copy/paste mistake, and not really written like that in your code?

Comment: The table was created in a rails project database using rails migration technique.

Comment: That was a copy/paste error as you said. Thanks for pointing out that.

Answer (score 0):

Run "describe [table_name]" against your manually created table, and against the one rails created, and compare the results.  You'll most likely find that there's a difference in the schema.  If it's not clear what to do after that, post the results here.